# Edit word document that is forwarded by a servlet from a webdav server

Tags: java, servlets, web, docx, webdav

I have a webdav server and to edit and save directly to the server I am using this protocol: ms-word:ofe|u|http://url.com/test.docx. But instead of directly using the document url I want to have a servlet that forwards or redirects to the file. When doing this though I get an error message Unexpected error from Microsoft office. Anyone know how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this, if you're using java, is probably to integrate [milton.io](http://milton.io)

Milton includes workarounds for all the different versions of windows and ms office so it actually works.

Its a framework designed to be attached to business web apps, and implementation is often trivial:

```
@PutChild
public Image uploadDoc(MyDocument doc, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        // do whatever persistence you want, database, webservice, etc
        return doc;
}
```

Comment: And there's a complete, but very simple, working example project here:
https://github.com/miltonio/milton2/blob/master/examples/tuts-anno1/src/main/java/com/helloworld/HelloWorldController.java

Comment: How can I use milton to achieve this?

Comment: Just implement milton according to the tutorials - http://milton.io/everyone/dash
And then use the sharepoint opendocuments object in client side code to open your docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454230%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Oh, i should add you dont need to use opendocuments API, using the "ms-word:ofe" protocol should be fine as well